# Xpath text()

Tags: xpath

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как мне найти тег по тексту внутри, если часть информации динамическая.

Я понимаю как найти статику:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</body>
```

Xpath:

```
//body/a[text()="Ссылка"]
```

А если я знаю только часть текста?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так:

```
//body/a[text()[contains(.,'Ссылка')]]
```

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться следующим вариантом, он производит поиск всех тэгов "а", которые содержать "часть текста"     `//a[contains(text(),'часть текста')]`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вроде вполне подробно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, после правки (час назад) — вполне.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да вроде и без неё нормально. Короткий кусок кода.